# Why do we use "make sense" rather than "making sense"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-tense, progressive-aspect

What is the difference between

1. This plan makes sense.
2. You aren't making any sense.

Why do we use "make sense" with present simple?

Comment: Do you know the difference in general between simple present and present progressive?

Answer (score 3):

The first example is in the present simple because it is stating a truth, a simple fact. A plan *works* or it doesn't. A plan can either *make sense* or not.

1. This plan works.
   My plan makes a lot of sense.
   This plan doesn't work.
   Your plan doesn't make any sense.

However, it's possible to talk about a plan that is currently working, maybe we witness an *evil plan* unfolding itself in real time. When we speak about an action that is in progress, the Present Continuous tense is commonly used.

2. You're working long hours.
   [My plan is working perfectly](https://tenor.com/en-GB/view/angelina-jolie-evil-laugh-maleficent-smile-gif-18400945).
   You **are making** a lot of sense.
   I hear what you're saying, but you **aren't making** any sense.